# Resistivity: related to $V/I$ or $dV/dI$?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits, temperature, electrical-resistance, non-linear-systems

The resistivity of tungsten is given by $\rho(T) \propto T^{1.209}$ (from Paul Gluck's Physics Project Lab] [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198704585)).

Let's assume that we can ignore the changes in the geometry of the wire due to temperature change.

Does that mean that for a tungsten filament with applied voltage $V$ and current $I$, we have $V/I\propto T^{1.209}$ or $dV/dI\propto T^{1.209}$?

Note that $V(I)$ is **not linear** in general (because of temperature changes during the experiment), so the distinction is relevant.

As I understand it, the former is *resistance*, and the latter is *differential-resistance*. Which one of them is related to temperature, as given above?

**Edit:**
My aim is to have a good model for a small light bulb that operates at a few volts. I'm interested in the transient stage, where the temperature changes. I've built a simulation which for arbitraty V(t) gives V(I). It assumes that the geometry of the filament is pretty constant, that P=IV gives the heat-flow, and the Stefan-Boltzman law of radiation. The question is, do I develop I(t) from I=V/R(T) or from dI=dV/R(T). These give different answers.

Comment: The resistivity is only nonlinear because a W wire's temperature, hence its resistance, in a bulb depends on the current.

Comment: @my2cts Yep. but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @my2cts's comment basically does answer your question: For fixed $T$, $V$ is a linear function of $I$, so your two expressions are equivalent. (In general, though, resistivity relates electric field and current density, not $\mathrm {d} E$ and $\mathrm{d} j$.)

Comment: @Toffomat How does this answer the question? It only deals with the case of fixed temperature. If I plot I(V) for some scenario with varying temperature, and choose some random point on it, will the expression for V/I relate to the temperature as the formula above? or dV/dI? both cannot be true at the same time. For example, I've written a simulation for the time development of current for a given V(t). The two scenarios give different outcomes

Comment: You may have written a time simulation for $V(t)$ but that makes no sense for this case unless you also plot the temperature, as well. Even when $\rho(T)$ is given that is not enough by itself, you also have to know how the resistor is *embedded* in its thermal environment. If the resistor is a thin film and is attached well to a heat sink then you know its temperature and is fixed to some value at which you can do your $V-I$ test. Anyhow, for a fixed temperature you get $V/I$, if your temp is not fixed it is still $V/I$ at the *measured* but not controlled temperature.

Comment: @rdbasha Tungsten does not have a nonlinear resistivity. $I/V=dI/dV$, as they should be calculated at constant temperature. Also, comments are not answers. Your question does not have an answer as the premiss is incorrect.

Comment: @hyportnex The simulation does, indeed, simulate the time development of the filament temperature, $T$ (under some assumptions). And so, the question stands. Each scenario leads to a different $I(t)$.

Comment: @my2cts The resistivity is a function of temperature, which may vary during measurement. This is why $V(I)$ is **not** linear for a light-bulb, as you may find if you preform the experiment, as I did. Of course, $V(I)$ depends on $V(t)$. Even a slowly-varying $V(t)$ leads to a nonlinear $V(I)$, because $\rho=\rho(T)$

Comment: @RdBasha This is very sloppy reasoning. In your opinion, does the resistance of tungsten depend on time? I did the experiment many times, before I had LEDs.

Comment: @my2cts In the given experiment, $\rho$ is indeed a function of time, as $\rho=\rho(T(t))$. The simulation needs to keep track of $\rho$ at different times.

Comment: @my2cts I think I understand what you are saying, correct me if I'm wrong. You are basically saying that $I=I(V,T)= f(T) \cdot V$, for some $f(T)$. you are saying that conductivity is $I/V=\partial{I}/\partial{V}$, but in general not $dI/dV$. Am I correct?

Comment: with a dc current or with a dc voltage you only measure $V/I$. To measure $dV/dI$ you need two current or voltage settings infinitesimally close so that the temperature is assumed to stay constant, then form a discrete approximation to the slope of the tangent line, This can be a dynamic measurement as it can be done easily with a amplitude modulated sine wave. . The measurement of $\rho$ is a static one, hence it results in $V/I$.

Comment: @RdBasha Exactly. Of course, no metal is ever _exactly_ linear but I suspected that you were, mathematically speaking, taking the total derivative while allowing T and t to vary. Effectively that would mean that you take I as the independent variable and variation due to T and t would occur via I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, based on the comments of my2cts.

The experimental resistivity $\rho(T)$ given above is related to $I/V$ (assuming no changes to the geometry due to the heating).

$I/V$ is the same as $\partial I/\partial V$ **at constant temperature**, because $I(V)$ is approximately linear for a metal filament **at constant temperature**. For other materials (such as diods) we might have a difference between resistance $V/I$ and differential resistance, $\partial V/ \partial I$ (at constant $T$). This is not the case here, as the nonlinear $I(V)$ here is due only to the temperature change.

Taking $dI/dV$ from an experiment with varying temperature gives no useful quantity.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, we distinguish [*static* and *differential resistivity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance#Static_and_differential_resistance). The differential resistivity depends from the point on the *current-voltage characteristics* where we calculate the derivative, so we cannot quite  a single value for it, but have to provide a full I-V curve.

The quoted values of resistivity are thus those for the *static restistivity*, calculated in the *linear response regime* - i.e., in the very beginning of the I-V curve where the differential $dV/dI$ and ratio $V/I$ are essentially the same:
$$
\lim_{V \rightarrow 0}\frac{V}{I}\rightarrow R=\frac{dV}{dI}|_{V=0}
$$

Note that what is manifestly non-linear here is the dependence on the resistivity on temperature. The dependence of current on voltage for tungsten has quite an extended linear part in the beginning (although it obviously becomes non-linear at very high voltages):
[image]

([image source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Current-versus-voltage-I-V-characteristics-of-a-tungsten-filament-sample-F-01-in_fig3_348078838))

Comment: So the quoted value is relevant only for the linear part? I'm interested in the nonlinear part as well. My aim is to have a good model for a light-bulb, which operates at a few volts. I've built a simulation which for arbitraty $V(t)$ gives $V(I)$. It assumes that the geometry of the filament is pretty constant, and that $P=IV$ gives the heat-flow, and the Stefan-Boltzman law of radiation. The question is, do I develop $I(t)$ from $I=V/R(T)$ or from $dI=dV/R(T)$. These give different answers. You raise another issue, which is that my  $\rho(T)$ for the nonlinear part might be wrong

Comment: @RdBasha depending on the geometry of the filament you may still be in the linear regime at several volts - you need to calculate the *resistance* $R=\rho l/A$.

Comment: As written above, let's ignore geometry changes in the filament. When I plot $I(V)$ experimentally, the linear regime is very small, due to large changes in temperature. Is it still correct to say that $I=V/R(T)$? Is the expression for $\rho(T)$ given above valid?

Comment: @RdBasha *the linear regime is very small, due to large changes in temperature* - I don't understand what you mean. These are two different dependencies: $\rho(T)$ and $I(V)$. Perhaps, you are not performing your experiment in a stationary regime (i.e., at a constant temperature?)

Comment: I am not. It's a light-bulb. It starts at room temperature, and quickly begins to shine in visible light.

Comment: @RdBasha there is a transient stage, where the filament is being heated, until it reaches a stable/stationary temperature - where the heat produced is balance by the dissipation. It is meaningless to speak about the IV characteristic in the transient stage, since different voltages/currents correspond to the same current/voltage depending on the temperature.

Comment: Why is it meaningless? This is what i measure in the lab, and this is what I wish to simulate. My only question is how to simulate it correctly.  do I develop $I(t)$ from $I=V/R(T)$ or from $dI=dV/R(T)$? from the other comments, I gather that the former is correct, and the latter is not.

Comment: @RdBasha It is changing in time - your current voltage characteristic is changing in time. The correct way to measure and IV curve would be to wait till the stationary regime establish itself and then measure. Transient regime is interesting, but more difficult to study and analyze.

Comment: @RdBasha, it sounds like you have the equipment on hand already to simply measure the bulb's characteristic and work out for yourself whether the results for static or differential resistance match better to the figures given in the literature.

Comment: As I understand it, though, incandescent bulbs are typically used at an operating point where differential resistance is negative, and the dependence you gave ($R\propto T^{1.209}$) never goes negative. So either this is a formula for the static resistance, or it's fit to a region of the I-V curve that isn't relevant to the usual operating point of a bulb.

Comment: @ThePhoton That's right. If the formula is for differential resistance, that means that the negative part must come from some other effect.